# Why is there no "Others" option on migration?

Tags: feature-request, migration

When we flag a post for migration the following options are available: 
[image]
SO is programming Q&A but we keep getting questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325542/webapps-vs-native-apps-which-is-better) which are more suitable for programmers.SE.

But there is no option for that in **Off-Topic > Migration**. same goes for a lot of [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tagged questions which are more suitable for android.SE.

At least having an **"Others"** options sounds sensible to me.

What do all the vets out there think about this.

Comment: Also related: [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382), posts like the one you referred to are **not** suitable for Programmers either. One of the comments states a **rewritten** question might do better on Programmers, but as currently written it is absolutely not a migration candidate.

Comment: Because [What is migration and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) says you should flag for moderator attention in these cases.

Comment: thank you very much for enlightening me. I hope I dont have to delete this post. :)