# "Automatic" move paths to complete Stack Exchange family

Tags: feature-request, migration

Well this is a given by [another topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262448/where-is-this-on-topic) I posted.
There I asked why a topic was closed. With the big hidden second part "instead of moved". It was closed for off-topic. Now I assumed that off-topic meant off topic for the whole family. As you could migrate it otherwise - so that was a reason why I posted this question "if it isn't here then instead of closing it should be migrated".

Now I was told there this isn't possible; I think that is quite a shame. And moving between Stack Exchange should be possible automatically by the "engine". This will especially become more important as the stackexchange family grows.
One can't be expected to know all flavours of Stack Exchange and know what is best where. So you can expect more and more "offtopic" as the Stack Exchange family gets more and more splintered.

Another good side effect of moving questions is that it bring to attention the existence of said site - it shows that a questions isn't fitted for site X. But "hey we got site Y - look there". It might move users to the less known sites!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I'm not saying move all off-topic - I'm saying add migration paths to all  stack exchange - by default. (So it doesn't have to be done by hand if a new site spawns from area 51). That way if someone notices something that may fit very well on another part of stack exchange he can request a move to there!

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited

Comment: Stackoverflow tends to migrate a lot of crap questions overwhelming the target site, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159604/why-close-as-off-topic-does-not-have-an-option-to-migrate-to-programmers-stack/159610#159610, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164774/remove-all-migration-targets-except-meta-stack-overflow  and http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3853/should-server-fault-be-removed-from-stack-overflows-migration-list

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can or can't questions be migrated after 60 days?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258349/can-or-cant-questions-be-migrated-after-60-days) and of [Why is there no “Others” option on migration?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261108/why-is-there-no-others-option-on-migration)

Comment: Migration should be for high quality questions, just posted in the wrong area.  With automatic paths, a ton of crap would get migrated over, get closed because it's crap, and that would bounce it.  And then we're back where we started, for nothing.

Answer (score 6):

> One can't be expected to know all flavours of Stack Exchange and know what is best where.

Of course you can. It's called doing a bit of trivial research. Stack Exchange openly advertises the goal of each site in the family. It would take all of a minute to read the list and pick the site that's appropriate for your question. Why is everybody so lazy?

With this in mind, auto-migration for every possible SE site is a needless waste.

Comment: No you can not - a human has a limited amount of memory he can take - and you can not remember, or expect, one to read all those faqs. By the end you forgot what was in the first. Expecting this is a form of elitism as you basically say "First do a degree in faq reading, then ask".

Comment: @paul23 No, this is expecting users to do their due diligence.  She's not saying read every single FAQ, she's saying read the ones of where the question may be on-topic.  I don't think it's too much to ask a user to expend a decent amount of their own time and effort to ensure we can help them better.

Comment: @paul23: I never said you have to learn the topic of every SE site by rote. Claiming "elitism" here is utterly barmy. "A degree in FAQ reading"? Sorry, but if you feel like you need a degree to read [a very simple web page](http://stackexchange.com/sites#name) then something else is very wrong.

Answer (score 4):

> Now I was told there this isn't possible

This is actually because of the age, not the lack of migration paths.  Questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated, even by moderators.  This is an intentional restriction in place to prevent high voted posts (from Stack Overflow) from skewing the vote totals on other sites.  This is because the (positive) voting is migrated with the question.  Had you discovered this could have been migrated in November or December, then you could have flagged the post and a moderator would have tried to migrated it (after consulting with moderators on the target site).

---

The reason for the limited options and limited functionality is migration itself is not an openly embraced feature, and is treated as somewhat of a dirty word.

The reason is the community as a whole fail to understand questions and site scopes before migrating.

- Only excellent posts that just happened to be posted on the wrong site should be considered for migration, but many users fail to grasp this concept.  Rather than looking for quality before migration, they only see the topic and say "hmmm, I think this would be better on Programmers (or Server Fault or Super User or `<insert your favorite site name here>`).
- Next, users fail to understand the scope of the target site.  They take the topic that they see and try to migrate, not understanding that the particular type of question or topic is not welcome on the target site.

Both of these issues now force 2 communities to clean up the post.

The limited migration option list is actually adjusted routinely based on migration success rate.  If a particular migration path (based on moderator migrations) is shown to be very successful, then it would be considered to be added in favor of a site that has less successful migrations.

To add another limit, migration to Beta sites is almost never done.  There will never be an existing migration path for the community to use, and moderators are extremely reluctant to migrate to those sites.  This is because there may not be a sufficient community on the Beta site to help moderate the question once it moves.

So if you encounter an excellent question that is less than 60 days old that you think is off-topic on Stack Overflow but on-topic elsewhere (that is not a Beta site), then flag it and tell a moderator which site you want to migrate it and why you think it is on-topic.

Comment: SO topics should be reposted (resulting in duplicates)?

Comment: For the small few that are high quality that don't/can't get migrated, then that's fine.  They aren't "duplicates" since they aren't on the same site.  And if the question is that much off-topic on SO, then it would probably get deleted from SO eventually.  But for crap questions, cross posting isn't going to help. It will just get closed & downvoted (and probably deleted) on the new site.